# How to give users in iOS the choice to choose their own currency

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, currency

I have an iOS app that keeps getting feedback from the users that they would like the ability to set their own currency type. Right now I'm using the `currencyFormatter.locale` to get the user local currency and use that for the app. My thought is that I might be able to create a tableView in the settings section of the app and let the users pick the currency they want to use.

I would save there desired currency and then use that instead of the locale one being displayed now.

To make this work what data would I need to pull? Would this data be supplied by Apple? I think I would need [currency codes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslocale/1642836-currencycode) but would this be the correct data to display for the user to choose from?

I found this [repo](https://github.com/danthorpe/Money) and it seems like this is something that would be useful, but it doesn't seem to be supported/updated anymore.

I just need some help being pointed in the correct direction for this, as my research isn't making any progress for me.

[Money](https://github.com/danthorpe/Money)

**EDIT**

I found an app that I think is doing something similar to what I would like to implement.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, you should make a list screen and let the users choose their desired currency from that. Save that currency and use it instead of the locale. You can use this code to get a list of currency names and currency symbols.

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSArray *currencyCodesArray = [NSLocale ISOCurrencyCodes];
NSMutableDictionary *currenciesDict = [NSMutableDictionary new];

for (NSString *currencyCode in currencyCodesArray) {

    NSString *currencyName = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCurrencyCode value:currencyCode];
    NSString *currencySymbol = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCurrencySymbol value:currencyCode];
    if (currencyName != nil && currencySymbol != nil) {
        [currenciesDict setValue:currencySymbol forKey:currencyName];
    }

}
return currenciesDict;
```

## Edit

Here's the same code in swift.

```
 let locale = NSLocale.current as NSLocale
    let currencyCodesArray = NSLocale.isoCurrencyCodes
    var currenciesDict = [String: String]()

    for currencyCode in currencyCodesArray {
                let currencyName = locale.displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.currencyCode, value : currencyCode)
                let currencySymbol = locale.displayName(forKey: NSLocale.Key.currencySymbol, value : currencyCode)

                if let currencySymbol = currencySymbol, let currencyName = currencyName {
                    currenciesDict[currencySymbol] = currencyName
                }
 }
 print(currenciesDict)
```

## Edit 2

Same code with custom model.

This is how your custom model will look like.

```
class CurrencyModel {
      var currencyName = ""
      var currencyCode = ""
}
```

And this is how the code will look like.

```
let locale = NSLocale.current as NSLocale
let currencyCodesArray = NSLocale.isoCurrencyCodes
var currencies = [CurrencyModel]()



for currencyCode in currencyCodesArray {
    let currencyName = locale.displayName(forKey: 

    NSLocale.Key.currencyCode, value : currencyCode)
    let currencySymbol = locale.displayName(forKey:NSLocale.Key.currencySymbol, value : currencyCode)

    if let currencySymbol = currencySymbol, let currencyName = currencyName {
        let currencyModel = CurrencyModel()
        currencyModel.currencyName = currencyName
        currencyModel.currencyCode = currencyCode

        currencies.append(currencyModel)
    }
}
print(currencies)
```

Comment: Would I need to create 2 arrays from the dictionary to use as a data source in a UITableView?

Comment: No. IMO you should create a custom model, say `CurrencyModel`. Add two properties to this model `currencyName` and `currencyCode`. Then you can have a single data source array of type `CurrencyModel`.

Comment: If you want, I can change the above code with `CurrencyModel`.

Comment: That would be great, I think I am following what you are saying, but would be great to check.

Comment: Thank you so much, really helped me out! I have a question on how to clean up the currency data but will ask that in a new question.

Comment: you seem to know a good amount of the currency area of swift. Does this question make sense to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52278097/how-to-reduce-the-amount-of-currency-codes-you-get-back-from-locale/52278228#52278228

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `currencySymbol` of the formatter instead:

```
let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
currencyFormatter.currencySymbol = "￥"
currencyFormatter.string(from: 123) // "￥123.00"
```

You can provide the user with a `UITextField` to let them enter any arbitrary string as the currency symbol.

If you want the user to choose a locale from a list and use that locale's currency symbol, the `currencySymbol` property of a `Locale` instance can also be used.

Clarification on locales and currencies:

Currencies and locales don't have a one-to-one correspondence. One currency can be used in multiple locales, but one locale usually has one corresponding currency, as there is a `currencySymbol` in `Locale`. And locale is used to decide where the currency symbol is. In France, for example, the currency symbol would be placed at the end. This means that if you just have a currency symbol, there is no "right" place for it in a string, because you have not specified a locale. So if you want the currency symbol to be at the user's expected place, ask the user for the locale they desire, and not the currency symbol. If you don't care whether the currency symbol is displayed at the user's expected place, then display it with the user's current locale.

Comment: If I let the user input any symbol, how would the currency format display the numbers correctly? Specifically where to put the currency symbol.

Comment: As I said in my last paragraph, you can make the user choose from a list of locales, and use the `currencySymbol` property of the locale instance. @icekomo

Comment: @icekomo You may also take into consideration of the fact that users' locales might not correspond to their desired currency, so to allow maximum customisation, currency symbol and locale should be separate options. Also note that you can't get the user's locale just by looking at their desired currency. Euros are used in many different locales.

Comment: So the idea is to let them pick whatever currency symbol they want to use ( which is why I thought displaying them in a table view or UIPicker might be best, and then use that as the format.  This is all new to me, so I'm trying to figure this out as I go. Does my approach to this problem work? @sweeper

Comment: @icekomo See the edit. You can't get the currency in the user's expected place if you don't ask for a locale. You can always use the user's current locale, which is what my first code snippet does.

Comment: I added some images from an app I found that is doing some similar. If I allowed the user to choose their currency, could I also get the locale from that currency, so that the user's device doesn't have to be in that geo-location to use the chose currency?

Comment: @icekomo You can't get a locale from a currency. You can make an educated guess for most currencies, but that's it. The app probably does this. For example, for the currency "Euro", how do you know whether user is in France or Germany or Italy or Spain etc?

Comment: By "educated guess", I mean for some currencies, like the Chinese Yuan or Japanese Yen, you can be quite certain that the locale is zh-cn and ja-jp respectively.