# How to reduce the amount of currency codes you get back from NSLocale.Key.currencyCode

Tags: swift, nslocale, currency-formatting

I have an ios app that I'm trying to allow the users to select which currency they want to use. Right now I have the full list of currencies but there seem to be some duplicates there such as:

[image]

Is there a way to filter out the others? The dollar isn't the only one with multiples some have date ranges listed with them.

I'm sure there is some built-in method that does this, but my searching so far hasn't pointed me in the right direction.

Here is what I am doing:

```
let locale = NSLocale.current as NSLocale
let currencyCodesArray = NSLocale.isoCurrencyCodes
var currencies = [CurrencyModel]()

for currencyCode in currencyCodesArray {
        let currencyName = locale.displayName(forKey:

            NSLocale.Key.currencyCode, value : currencyCode)
        let currencySymbol = locale.displayName(forKey:NSLocale.Key.currencySymbol, value : currencyCode)

        if let _ = currencySymbol, let currencyName = currencyName {
            let currencyModel = CurrencyModel()
            currencyModel.currencyName = currencyName
            currencyModel.currencyCode = currencyCode

            currencies.append(currencyModel)
        }
    }
```

And then using that data in a talbeView

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as! CurrencyTableViewCell

    cell.name.text = currencies[indexPath.row].currencyName
    cell.symbol.text = currencies[indexPath.row].currencyCode

    return cell
}
```

And this is my currency model

```
class CurrencyModel {
var currencyName = ""
var currencyCode = ""
```

}

Comment: Please show what research you've undertaken, what you've already tried, what didn't work, code samples etc. Read [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Where is `currencyCodesArray` coming from? Please give more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using

```
Locale.commonISOCurrencyCodes
```

rather than

```
Locale.isoCurrencyCodes
```

Answer (score -3):

If they all have that form: ie bit you want (bit you don't want) you could search for regular expressions. Search the list to find the shortest ones and keep those. You'd then have to do something about other countries which use dollars, or other currencies etc.